# Covariance of $a \otimes b$ for independent random variables $a$ and $b$

Tags: covariance, independence, covariance-matrix

This question is closely related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271905/covariance-of-kronecker-product), but I do not fully understand the answer of @Taylor.

Suppose I have $N$-x-$1$ random variables $\mathbf{a}$ and $M$-x-$1$  $\mathbf{b}$ which are independent of each other with known covariances matrices $A$ and $B$ and non-zero means $E(\mathbf a)$ and $E(\mathbf b)$. 
What is the covariance matrix $C$ of random variable $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b}$ in terms of $A$ and $B$?

---

First, as $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are independent, one can show that $E(c) = E(a) \otimes E(b)$. 
Then, the covariance matrix is
\begin{align*}
&E[(\mathbf{c}-E(c))E(\mathbf{c}-E(c))^T] \\
&= E\left\{
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
a_1\mathbf{b} -E(a_1)E(\mathbf b)\\
a_2\mathbf{b} -E(a_2)E(\mathbf b)\\
\vdots \\
a_m\mathbf{b} -E(a_m)E(\mathbf b)
\end{array}\right]
\left[a_1\mathbf{b}^T - E(a_1)E(\mathbf{b})^T, \cdots, a_m\mathbf{b}^T - E(a_m)E(\mathbf{b})^T\right] 
\right\} \\
&= 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
E[a_1a_1\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T] - E(a_1)E(a_1)E(\mathbf{b})E(\mathbf{b})^T &  \cdots & E[a_1a_m \mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T] - E(a_1)E(a_m)E(\mathbf{b})E(\mathbf{b})^T\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
E[a_ma_1 \mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T] - E(a_m)E(a_1)E(\mathbf{b})E(\mathbf{b})^T  & \cdots & E[a_ma_m \mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T] - E(a_m)E(a_m)E(\mathbf{b})E(\mathbf{b})^T
\end{array} \right]
\end{align*}

For the case with $E(a)=E(b)=0$ each of the expectations in the previous matrix would split up, and one would get $\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{a}) \otimes \operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{b})$ for the covariance matrix.

But what about the case with non-centered $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Your notation appears to overcomplicate an inherently simple situation: you require the covariance of $a_ib_j$ and $a_kb_l$ for indexes $i,j,k,l$. The independence assumption makes it easy to compute the required moments in terms of the moments of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First
$$
E[\mathbf{c}] = E[\mathbf{a}\otimes \mathbf{b}] = E[\mathbf{a}] \otimes E[\mathbf{b}] = \mu_a \otimes \mu_b
$$
by independence.

Then 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}[\mathbf{c}] &= E\left[ (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} - \mu_a \otimes \mu_b)(\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} - \mu_a \otimes \mu_b)'\right] \tag{defn of var}\\
&= E\left[\{(\mathbf{a}-\mu_a)\otimes (\mathbf{b} - \mu_b) \}\{(\mathbf{a}-\mu_a)\otimes (\mathbf{b} - \mu_b)\}'\right] \tag{properties of kron}\\
&= \operatorname{Var}\left[ \tilde{\mathbf{a}} \otimes \tilde{\mathbf{b}} \right]
\end{align*}
and we can use the linked post's result because these new vectors are zero-mean. But yeah, I think that second to last equality is worth doing out. Watch out, because you seem to have a few typos: e.g. $E[(\mathbf{c}-E(c))E(\mathbf{c}-E(c))^T]$ .